# Symfony 4 > filter a list of results, the best way

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm working on a new Symfony 4 project.

I have a list of ***Speakers***, and a list of ***Themes***, and I have a ManyToMany relations between.

```php
class Speakers
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Themes", inversedBy="speakers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="speakers_themes")
     */
    private $themes;

    /**
     * Speakers constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->themes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Themes[]
     */
    public function getThemes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->themes;
    }

    /**
     * @param Themes $theme
     * @return Speakers
     */
    public function addTheme(Themes $theme): self
    {
        if (!$this->themes->contains($theme)) {
            $this->themes[] = $theme;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Themes $theme
     * @return Speakers
     */
    public function removeTheme(Themes $theme): self
    {
        if ($this->themes->contains($theme)) {
            $this->themes->removeElement($theme);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
class Themes
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Speakers", mappedBy="themes")
     */
    private $speakers;

    /**
     * Themes constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->speakers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Speakers[]
     */
    public function getSpeakers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->speakers;
    }

    /**
     * @param Speakers $speaker
     * @return Themes
     */
    public function addSpeaker(Speakers $speaker): self
    {
        if (!$this->speakers->contains($speaker)) {

            $this->speakers[] = $speaker;
            $speaker->addTheme($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Speakers $speaker
     * @return Themes
     */
    public function removeSpeaker(Speakers $speaker): self
    {
        if ($this->speakers->contains($speaker)) {

            $this->speakers->removeElement($speaker);
            $speaker->removeTheme($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

I want to be able to filter the list of speakers, depending of the themes.

Since the list of themes is short (3 items), I thought of a select box, with the possibility of choosing a theme to filter.

But I don't know what's the best way to do this:

- Build a specific form, to filter ?

```php
class SpeakersFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('themes', EntityType::class,
                [
                    'class'    => Themes::class,
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true
                ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Filter'
                ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'method'     => Request::METHOD_GET,
//                'data_class' => null,
                'data_class' => Speakers::class,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I tried to build a form like you can see below.
In the ***configureOptions*** method, I specify the method to GET, and I was hoping that I can pass some get params to filter but it's not working.

I have an error:
***The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class App\Entity\Speakers, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of App\Entity\Speakers.***

If  I follow the advice and put the option 'data_class' to null, I dont have an error but I'm not sure It's working, regarding the strange params it sends to the URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/speakers/?speakers_filter%5Bthemes%5D%5B%5D=2&speakers_filter%5Bsave%5D=&speakers_filter%5B_token%5D=ClBi9xzMrkM72niXNnkbMi1i-3gWMQ2sgfIxY0M1Pi8

Can somebody can help ? Thank you so much from a Symfony newbie.